# get all configurations of a queue manager in websphere MQ

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

Is there a way to get all the properties of queues, channels, etc,. with a single mq command and store it in a file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the [MS03](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&q1=mA1J&uid=swg24000673&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en) SupportPac will do what you require.  Quoting...

**Abstract**
This SupportPac (saveqmgr) saves all the objects, such as queues, channels, etc, defined in either a local or remote queue manager, to a file.

Comment: It is worth noting that MS03 also saves authorization records.  As of V7.1 the [dmpmqcfg](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa22720_.htm) command replaces MS03 with a native, fully supported command.